# Tests with embedded database in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core

I come from a Java background, and in Java I used to write unit tests (although they were closer to integration tests) using an embedded, in memory database instance. I found tests like those much more useful than tests which include mocking, which may hide mistakes, and the mocking process is error prone itself. I also used things like embedded brokers, embedded NoSQL databases and so on, which did the work very well.

However, in the .Net ecosystem, I'm struggling to find a parallel. The docs only show [the approach I do not like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) (and a rather basic one). Is there something like [Mongo2Go](https://github.com/Mongo2Go/Mongo2Go) (rare example of what I am looking for), but for relational databases? Is there a different approach I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options for testing the Entity Framework.

[InMemory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) is designed for tests that do not require strict relational database behavior.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo_DoesBar_WhenBaz()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "foo_bar_baz")
        .Options;

    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

[SQLite in-memory mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite) is appropriate when tests require more relational behavior.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo_DoesBar_WhenBaz()
{
    var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
    connection.Open();

    try
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection)
            .Options;

        using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
        {
            ...          
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it will do for now :-)